# Problem in the bookmark in PDF document

Tags: indexing, bookmarks

I have some problems with the bookmarks. In the PDF I have this:

[image]

The problem is:
part I called "Stato dell'Arte" contains its chapters and the part II "Progettazione" and part III is contained in part II.
Now, I want that Part I, II, III are on the same level and each of them contains its chapters. How can I produce this?

Update1: I found that the problem is when I open a `\section{...}`, without them it works

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, italian]{report}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\usepackage[final,backref,breaklinks,pagebackref,colorlinks]{hyperref}
%HYPERREF per uso con con pdf (con bookmark)
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{verbatim}





\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}




\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter.}{2pc}{}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}   % For consistency in all headings

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\center 
\textsc{\LARGE Università degli studi di Salerno}\\[1cm] 
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{img/logo_vett.eps} \\[1cm]
\textsc{\large DIPARTIMENTO DI INFORMATICA}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large Progetto di Sicurezza Dei Dati}\\[0.5cm]
%\textsc{\Large MyUnimol}\\[0.5cm] 
 \HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \large \bfseries MVS-CLOUD: Una infrastruttura Cloud Storage multi vista per la protezione di dati da coercitori}\\[0.4cm] 
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Candidato:}\\
XXX\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Relatore:} \\
Prof. XXX\\

\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2.5cm]

{Anno accademico 2015/2016}\\


\vfill

\end{titlepage}     
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}    

\chapter*{Abstract}
CIAO
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    %\listoftables


\chapter{Introduzione}
CIAO



\part{Stato dell'Arte}

\chapter{Cloud}
\section{CIAO} %comment this section to see what I want.





\chapter{Problemi}
CIAO%\input{Problemi.tex}


\part{Progettazione MVS-Cloud}
\chapter{Problemi}
CIAO%\input{IngegneriaSoftware.tex}

\part{Inside D-Cloud}
\chapter{Proof of Concept}
CIAO%\input{SoluzioneFinale.tex}



\chapter{Conclusioni}
CIAO%\input{Conclusioni.tex}

\begin{thebibliography}{ssssss}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}% inserisce nell'indice la bibliografia

\bibitem{} ``The NIST Definition of Cloud Computing''
\url {http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-145/SP800-145.pdf}


\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  do you mean "index", or is your concern how the parts are listed in the table of contents?  what document class do you use?  (it would be easier to answer your question if your example is able to be compiled.)

Comment: I edited my code and added an example

Comment: @CiroRa: After enabling the various `\part` and `\chapter` commands I find that they the parts on the same level and the chapters are indented in the bookmarks (this is wwhat  you call 'index')

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I found the problem, the section command gives me trouble....

Comment: @CiroRa: I don't really understand, but is your problem solved now?

Comment: No, I found that problem is when I add sections. Erasing them I have no problem, but I need to have sections. So how can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resetting of chapter numbers by part confuses `hyperref` and does one anchors both for the links as well as wrong levelling in the bookmark.

This can be changed by a redefinition of `\theHchapter` in the `\AtBeginDocument` hook.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, italian]{report}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother%

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}




\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter.}{2pc}{}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}   % For consistency in all headings

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}


\usepackage[final,backref,breaklinks,pagebackref,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=3]{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
%HYPERREF per uso con con pdf (con bookmark)


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{chapter.\thepart.\thechapter}
}




\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\center 
\textsc{\LARGE Università degli studi di Salerno}\\[1cm] 

\textsc{\large DIPARTIMENTO DI INFORMATICA}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large Progetto di Sicurezza Dei Dati}\\[0.5cm]
%\textsc{\Large MyUnimol}\\[0.5cm] 
 \HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \large \bfseries MVS-CLOUD: Una infrastruttura Cloud Storage multi vista per la protezione di dati da coercitori}\\[0.4cm] 
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Candidato:}\\
XXX\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Relatore:} \\
Prof. XXX\\

\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2.5cm]

{Anno accademico 2015/2016}\\


\vfill

\end{titlepage}     
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}    

\chapter*{Abstract}
ABSTRACT
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
% \listoftables




%\chapter{Introduzione}
%\input{Introduzione.tex}

\part{Stato dell'Arte}

\chapter{Cloud}
\section{Foo}
%\input{Statodellarte.tex}

\chapter{Problemi}
%\input{Problemi.tex}


\part{Progettazione MVS-Cloud}
\chapter{Problemi}
%\input{IngegneriaSoftware.tex}

\part{Inside D-Cloud}
\chapter{Proof of Concept}
%\input{SoluzioneFinale.tex}



\chapter{Conclusioni}
%\input{Conclusioni.tex}

% This is only needed if the bibliography should appear in the bookmarks like a part!
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\toclevel@chapter}{-1}%
\makeatother



\begin{thebibliography}{ssssss}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}% inserisce nell'indice la bibliografia

\bibitem{} ``The NIST Definition of Cloud Computing''
\url {http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-145/SP800-145.pdf}



\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks for your time. what did I miss?

Comment: @CiroRa: As I explained (in short) in the answer: Resetting the chapter counter by the `\part` command will lead to wrong page/hyperlink anchors and the levelling system gets confused, this is why `section` causes wrong levels in the bookmarks. Using `hyperref` is quite convenient but changing counter setups has to be done with care!